# Does service still run in foreground after "show notifications" is un-checked?

Tags: android, service, notifications, foreground

I know that to run as a foreground service, you need to show a notification. My app runs a service as a foreground service, and it shows a notification.

**However, if the user goes into Settings -> Apps- > My app -> and un-checks "show notifications", will the service continue to run as a foreground service?**

I assumed that yes, it will continue to run as a foreground service.

However, I recently noticed my service was killed by the system, and saw this in the logcat:

Killing 2647:com.myapp.myapp:Service/u0a122 (adj 15): kill background

The service was killed, and it did not restart itself. This is on Android 4.4.2. Worst of all, onDestroy was not called, so I couldn't even release some wake-locks.

Comment: Most likely Android terminated the entire process, and so your wakelocks would no longer be an issue. AFAIK, notifications from foreground services are unaffected by "show notifications" and therefore there should be no change in behavior: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/07/30/notifications-foreground-services-android-4p3.html

Comment: @CommonsWare yes I had read your blog entry. My wakelocks held until I FC-ed the app actually. It was still showing under "cached processes" but no longer under "Running Processes".

Comment: That's rather strange. Can you reliably reproduce this condition?

Comment: I'll have to wait and see if it happens again. I have been running my app like this with "show notifications" unchecked for a week with no problems, but today it did this twice. What is the normal procedure for when a foreground service is killed? Should it not restart itself?

Comment: Whether it is restarted depends on what you return from `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think herein lies the problem. There seems to be a problem with Android respecting START_STICKY in 4.4.2. Have you seen this bug? https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63793&can=5&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: See comment #17 on that bug. I am aware of these reports; I have not investigated personally.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, that's my current setup under which eventually even my foreground service was killed and not restarted.

Comment: @Flyview, So to clarify, is the problem here that when you swipe away the app's task in Recents, then your service is killed either immediately or not too long after?

Comment: @Sam I'm not sure what killed it. Yes, usually swiping an app away from recents will kill the process. However, under normal circumstances services should be able to restart themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes; the service still runs in foreground when "Show notifications" is unticked.

Run `adb shell dumpsys activity services` and check the value of the `isForeground` flag for your service.

```
  * ServiceRecord{e66dea9 u0 com.example.foregroundservice/.ForegroundService}
    intent={cmp=com.example.foregroundservice/.ForegroundService}
    packageName=com.example.foregroundservice
    processName=com.example.foregroundservice:backgroundproc
    baseDir=/data/app/com.example.foregroundservice-2/base.apk
    dataDir=/data/user/0/com.example.foregroundservice
    app=ProcessRecord{254dd51 14363:com.example.foregroundservice:backgroundproc/u0a65}
    isForeground=true foregroundId=101 foregroundNoti=Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null tick defaults=0x0 flags=0x40 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
    createTime=-55s70ms startingBgTimeout=--
    lastActivity=-55s70ms restartTime=-55s70ms createdFromFg=true
    startRequested=true delayedStop=false stopIfKilled=false callStart=true lastStartId=1
```

### Compatibility (using official Android emulators)

#### Not working:

- 4.0.2 (the "Show notifications" setting isn't available)

#### Working:

- 4.1.2
- 4.2.2
- 4.3.1
- 4.4.2
- 5.0.2
- 5.1.1
- 6.0
- 7.0
- 7.1